# Как скопировать только каталоги в Linux?

Tags: linux, unix

Всем привет.
В каталоге `/crm` лежат штук 200 подкаталогов и тысяч 6 просто разных файлов.
Как скопировать только 200 подкаталогов (рекурсивно – со всеми под-под-каталогами и файлами) в папку `/crm_bak`?

То есть, в исходном каталоге:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── dir3
│   │   └── file4
│   └── file3
├── file1
└── file2
```

А после копирования должно получиться:

```
$ tree
.
└── dir1
    ├── dir3
    │   └── file4
    └── file3
```

Comment: С такой постановкой вопроса можно просто `cp -R /crm/* /crm_bak/`

Comment: cp -r /src/*/ dst/

Answer (score 2):

Только каталоги:

```
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /откуда/ /куда/
```

С остальным определитесь: "только каталоги" или "только 200 подкаталогов(рекурсивно - со всеми под-под-каталогами))) **и файлами**)"

---

Возможно, речь о:

```
find /откуда/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec cp -r {} /куда/ \;
# но можно и rsync вместо cp использовать, зависит от конкретики
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Скрипт копирует только каталоги, оставляя файлы на месте
# ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЙ 1-й параметр - откуда выполняем копирование.
# ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЙ 2-й параметр - куда выполняем копирование.
# Целевой каталог должен уже существовать

# Обработка скрытых каталогов с помощью звёздочки
shopt -s dotglob

# Просматриваем заданный параметром каталог
pushd $1
for dir in *
do
    if [ -d $dir ] 
    then
        # Это директория - выполняем рекурсивное копирование
        cp -R $dir $2/$dir
    fi
done

# Возвращаемся обратно
popd
```